# Loading a ZipFile from within the apk on android

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm creating a plattforming game with the LibGDX framework at the moment.
A level file in my Engine is a zip file containing a textfile with the leveldata and an asset folder containing all assets for the level like textures and sounds.
I'm loading a level like this:

```
    ZipFile archive = null;
    try {
        archive = new ZipFile(new File("test.zip"));
    } catch (ZipException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

It is working perfectly on desktop with the level file being next to the jar, but on android it doesn't. It throws a file not found exeption.
This is logical, because

```
new ZipFile(new File("test.zip"));
```

refers to a zip file next to the apk. Now I want to either load them from the assets folder, or load them from a levels folder next to the apk. I tried putting the zipfile into the assets/maps folder and loading it with the following code:

```
new ZipFile(Gdx.files.internal("maps/test.zip").file());
```

but that resulted in the same file not found exeption.
So my question is:**How do I load a zip file from within the assets folder of libGDX?**

Comment: Did you check if the file was created (doens't throw an error)? If you safe the file to the SD card, make sure you have the android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission set.

Comment: What if the android device doesn't have an sd card? A lot of devices don't have an sd card, and I also want to target those. And what do you mean by "check if the file was created"? How do I acces  the files inside the apk? Because the assets folder is is inside of the apk to my understanding, or am I wrong?

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/File-handling , I guess you can find everything there.

Comment: I have read through that, but it doesn't really make things more clear to me. To my understanding after reading through it, Gdx.files.internal("maps/test.zip") should return the filehandle to the file test.zip located in the folder maps, which is in the assets folder, which it does, but when getting the file from it with ".file()", the file for some reason doesn't exist.